# I have a tabactivity class but I need to have google map under one tab without extending the class as MapActivity

Tags: android, tabactivity, mapactivity

I have already coded an app with a class which is extending tabactivty, but under one of the tabs I need to have a google map, but I don't want to extend the class with MapActivity, is there any way t use map rather than extending the main class with MapActivity?

because if I extend it with MapActivity I get loads of error.

Many thanks.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489593/mapview-and-fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I knew, you have to use MapActivity to get a MapView.

What errors did you get if you extends MapActivity?

Answer (score 0):

You could try Actionbar Sherlock library. Maybe that could help