# MapActivity in a fragment

Tags: android

I have a `FragmentActivity`:

```
public class parking extends FragmentActivity { }
```

It has 3 tabs, the second and third are lists, solved.

```
public class tab2 extends Fragment{ }
```

But the first one is a map, so, I can't extend Fragment and a `MapActivity`.

How can I solve it?

Comment: If you're using the compatibility apis I think you have to make another activity that uses MapActivity, there is MapFragment if you're using 3.0+ apis

Comment: Thank you very much.

You said something interesting for me, can I show a map in my app whith minSDKVersion = 8???

thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109336/mapview-in-a-fragment-honeycomb

Answer (score 5):

There is no support for MapFragment, Android team says is working on it since Android 3.0. Here more information about the issue http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15347&utm_source=buffer&buffer_share=acc72
But what you can do is create a Fragment that returns a MapActivity. Here is a code example. Thanks to inazaruk: https://github.com/inazaruk/examples/tree/master/MapFragmentExample
How it works:

- **MainFragmentActivity** is the activity that extends FragmentActivity
  and hosts two MapFragments.
- **MyMapActivity** extends MapActivity and
  has MapView.
- **LocalActivityManagerFragment** hosts
  LocalActivityManager.
- **MyMapFragment** extends LocalActivityManagerFragment and with help of TabHost creates
  internal instance of MyMapActivity.

if you have any doubt please let me know

Comment: Map Api version 2 supports now Map Fragment https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment

Answer (score 4):

Google released the [Map API Version 2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/). This finally allows us to use a MapFragment and a [SupportMapFragment](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment). This allows adding Maps to ViewPagers and to Activities that do not extend MapActivity.