# MapView (android maps api v2) inside fragment layout doesnt show

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-maps-v2

I am using viewpager to swipe between 2 action bar tabs (used eclipse wizard for this kind of navigation). I am using android maps v2 api.

I want to have mapview, button and textview inside one of my tabs (i guess having mapfragment is not possible).

I inflate layout for my fragment from xml like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_tab_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

My first_tab_fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp" >
</com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="133dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

MapView is not displayed, just textview and button. I also get no errors. Do i have to write some code  to initialize mapview?

Comment: take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324744/mapactivity-in-a-fragment

Answer (score 28):

I solved it by adding this code to onCreateView:

```
   // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
    mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapview);

    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.onResume(); //without this, map showed but was empty 

    // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
    map = mapView.getMap(); 
    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


    // Needs to call MapsInitializer before doing any CameraUpdateFactory calls
    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(44.14, 14.2), 10);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

Comment: If you want the `mapView` to work properly, you may want to handle all the lifecycles methods at the right places. You should put the `mapView.onResume()` in your Activity's `onResume()` method, the `onPause()` in `the onPause()` and so on.