# MapView does not load properly inside fragment. Strange behaviour on Google PLay services 9.4.0

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-play-services, android-mapview

I am using MapView inside a fragment. Now it does not load. (Or to be precise, it loads but it does not load. Yes, its weird, pics attached.)

Some logs on console when map loads (or fails to load/tries to load)

```
 W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
 I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:1
 I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 1
 D/ChimeraFileApk: Primary ABI of requesting process is armeabi-v7a
 I/art: DexFile_isDexOptNeeded failed to open oat file '/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@data@com.google.android.gms@app_chimera@m@00000006@DynamiteModulesA_GmsCore_prodlmp_xxhdpi_release.apk@classes.dex' for file location '/data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000006/DynamiteModulesA_GmsCore_prodlmp_xxhdpi_release.apk': Failed to open oat filename for reading: No such file or directory
 D/ChimeraFileApk: Classloading successful. Optimized code found.
 D/GoogleCertificates: com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates module is loaded
 Fetched 163 Google release certificates
 Fetched 318 Google certificates
 D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
```

Here is the code :

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


    mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
    mapView.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

And on MapReady, I do this :

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap;
    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    map.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Needs to call MapsInitializer before doing any CameraUpdateFactory calls
    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(43.1, -87.9), 10);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
}
```

The map is not even loaded. When I keep clicking on it. Then after a few seconds it suddenly starts showing zoomed, but does not respond to any user interaction. Nothing happens whether i click it pinch zoom it.
Now when I use a SUPPORT MAP FRAGMENT, it loads immediately and perfectly. So, MY API KEY IS CORRECT AND INTERNET IS PERFECTLY FINE.
But MAP VIEW IN THE FRAGMENT DOES NOT WORK.

I also checked this link and the logs are same like I am getting :[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38522352/android-logcat-is-flooded-with-w-google-maps-android-api-glhudoverlay-deprecat)

Sometimes when I keep clicking on it , say 10 20 times, then after few seconds only some part of map is visible. But still no user interaction. Nothing happens, no matter what I do.

Now here are the screenshots of the MapView :

[image: This is when fragment loads.]

[image]

[image]

Please help me, can anyone tell me if its a bug on my side or a real bug on Android's mapview. 
Has anyone able to use MapView inside fragment with latest Google Play services ?

Please help me, I am stuck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [MapView](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView#public-method-summary),

> Users of this class must forward all the life cycle methods from the `Activity` or `Fragment` containing this view to the corresponding ones in this class.

You must forward on the following methods:

- onCreate(Bundle)
- onResume()
- onPause()
- onDestroy()
- onSaveInstanceState()
- onLowMemory()

Example, you must call `onResume()` method from the parent Activity/Fragment's corresponding method.

Try adding the code as given in this SO post - [MapView (android maps api v2) inside fragment layout doesnt show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582110/mapview-android-maps-api-v2-inside-fragment-layout-doesnt-show) .