# Best way to implement tabs with lists, fragments and maps?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-maps

I'm trying to "port" an iOS app to Android. 
The original iOS app workflow is:

```
Tab 1
  List1 -> Detail -> DetailMap

Tab 2
  List2 -> Detail -> DetailMap

Tab 3
  Map -> Detail
```

Where "List1" and "List2" are lists of places, "Detail" shows info about a place, "DetailMap" shows where the place is on the map. "Map" is a simple map with markers the user can click to reach "Detail".

What's the best way to implement this workflow in Android?

I know I should avoid using a TabActivity (deprecated), and instead use an action bar and fragments to provide navigation tabs. 
Ok, but then how to implement navigation from "List1" to "Detail", and from "Detail" to "DetailMap"? I don't think it's possible to have fragments inside a fragment?

And what about the maps? I don't think it's possible to have a mapview inside a fragment, right?

I must be missing something (maybe a lot)...

Comment: So basically you want to have a list, when the item in the list is clicked it takes you to details activity, and a button on the details activity takes you to the Detail map? Or tabs activity. YOu could use Action bar too for this.

Comment: @coder_For_Life22 Could you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: So is List2 in a tab, a a actually list of items?

Comment: @coder_For_Life22 Yes List2 is a list of items. Let's say List1 is a list of Restaurants, and List2 is a list of Hotels. They are in different tabs in the original iOS app I'm trying to port.

Comment: SO why dont you have a 3 buttons for each list for restaurants, hotels, and what else. And then each button launches a http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html with a listview in it and corresponding tabs for lists, details, and mapsview

Comment: @coder_For_Life22 I'd like to avoid using TabActivity, because it's deprecated. But if there is no other way, I'll live with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the best components for this is the ViewPager. 
http://tamsler.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-viewpager-and-fragments.html

and

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

You can see it in action in the new Android Market, or the Google+ App for Android.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just one thing: are you sure we can use a MapActivity as one of the page in viewpager?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure -> haven't tried it. But this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109336/mapview-in-a-fragment-honeycomb looks promising. Good luck

Comment: Btw, I have succesfully implemented a ViewPager using Fragment, and a Map... It required some severe googling, but there are nice solutions