# Fragments TabHost with Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

1. I have a StartActivity that extends `FragmentActivity`. The layout contains the calling for the fragment, `<fragment class="bla.bla.bal.TabsFragment">`
2. The TabsFragment contains the interaction between the fragments. All these works fine with different fragments.
3. Now I have another `Activity` that extend `MapActivity`. I would like to include this map and keep the `TabHost` still at the bottom of the view. Does anyone know how to do this?

I've checked [Best way to implement tabs with lists, fragments and maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566566/best-way-to-implement-tabs-with-lists-fragments-and-maps)  and [need fast help for Google Maps in fragments with compatibility android support libs for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781650/need-fast-help-for-google-maps-in-fragments-with-compatibility-android-support-l) but I still have troubles...