# Using Google Maps in fragments with compatibility android support libs for android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I want to use google maps as one of the fragments of many. I found no other way then the one mentioned in the following way...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8126287

and I was successful
But now I have 2 problems

1. I want to call a public method of the MyMapActicity(MyMapActivity is created as mentioned in the link given above) from another fragment. i.e. e.g. if I have fragmentA as some other fragment and MapFragment as a fragment related to MyMapActivity(created with help of above link) then I want to call a method from MyMapActivity from FragmentA. How do I do this.
2. I also want to resume the fragment with it is called...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer at:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8126287

The link also provides a very nice example to follow. As I have only one activity this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Action Bar Sherlock?  http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: Hi thank you for the response.
But I cant use this actionbar as I have to stick to the design which have no action bars..
any other help is most welcomed...
Thank you
Raj

Comment: You don't have to use the Action Bar stuff.  There is a FragmentMapActivity class in the plugins folder. You can use that to add fragments with maps to you activity.   https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
I will definitely try the stuff...
Raj

Comment: FragmentMapActivity class was available only in ABS 3.xx. It isn't available in ABS 4.