# fragments and mapView

Tags: android

can i use fragments and map view in the same activity. I have seen a subject talking about this: [MapView in a Fragment (Honeycomb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109336/mapview-in-a-fragment-honeycomb)
I was than able to create a fragment list and a map view in the right.
Can i print other fragments under the map?
I tried to do this but got a problem because my mainActivity extends FragmentActivity and not Fragment.

Here is a picture that explain whet i want to do

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to do the same thing and have found this solution so far, though I haven't tried it myself yet.

[MapView in a Fragment (Honeycomb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109336/mapview-in-a-fragment-honeycomb)

Comment: I tried going that route and just abandonned, my app would crash and I didn't have time to get it to work. I wrote an Activity just for the map part.