# Call functions of Activities Belonging to a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mapview

I am working with multiple `Fragments` under Android and am confused on how to send and receive data from embedded apps.

For a simple explanation, I have a `ListFragment` and a `MapFragment` using the method explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109336/mapview-in-a-fragment-honeycomb).  This means that the `List` lives in the `ListFragment` class, however the `MapActivity` is an `Activity` that is called under the `LocalActivityManagerFragment`.

Everything works on the individual `Fragments`: `Lists` of waypoints, waypoints and current location implemented on the `MapFragment`.  I also understand how to use `getFragmentManager()` to get individual `Fragments` and use their events.  However, I cannot use this method to access a function under `MapActivity`.  How can I use a command such as `goToLocation` (created under `MapActivity`) if I click on an item on the `ListView`, if I can't simply use `getFragmentManager`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For communication between a Fragment and an activity:

Activity > Fragment:

Call on the public methods of the fragment using this.

```
TestFragment testFrag = (TestFragment) getFragmentManager().getFragmentById(R.id.testfragment);

if(testFrag != null && testFrag.isAdded())
    testFrag.testMethod("Test");
```

Fragment > Activity

To send messages to the activity you need to use an interface so in the fragments class add this: (Not in any method)

```
public interface testInterface{
    public void testMethod(String test);
}

testInterface mCallback;

@Override
public void onAttact(Activity a){
    try{
        mCallback = (testInterface) a;
    }catch(Exception e){
        //TODO
    }
}
```

then in any method you can go and call this:

```
mCallback.testMethod("hello");
```

then for the activity make it so it `implements testInterface` and import the interface

and then have this method in the activity

```
@Override
public void testMethod(String testString){

}
```

:) Just ask for anything more.

---

Edit

From my first read of your question I thought this is what you wanted sorry, could still cover what you wanted.

I think what your asking for is just a onItemClick method right?

so in the interface you could have

```
public void onItemClicked(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id);
```

then when onItemClick has been called in the fragment you can use this in it

```
mCallback.onItemClicked(parent, view, position, id);
```

and then in the activity, given its implementing the interface you can have

```
@Override
public void onItemClicked(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

}
```