# Action Bar in API Level > 3.0 but Still Support API < 3.0

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-maps, android-compatibility

Yet another compatibility question.

**THE PROBLEM**

I need to use a `tabbed action bar` in api level 3.0 and greater to switch between `fragments`. However, I also need to be able to switch between these `fragments` somehow in api level < 3.0.

The spanner in the works is the fact that I have already downloaded a custom compatibility library that allows me to use `google maps` with `fragments` and therefore I can't use a library.

**THE QUESTION**

How can I implement a tabbed `ActionBar` solution in 3.0 and greater and also cater for the bigger market that is 3.0 and less?

Any help would be grand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to figure a solution a while ago, it's just taken me a while to post it here.

This is the solution that works for me. I needed to use an ActionBar but I also needed to use the MapActivity as well as the FragmentActivity hence not being able to use ActionBarSherlock.

What I did was the following:

- Created a fragment called CCActionBar which handles the touching of the CCTab's by adding itself as a listener(explained below). It also inflates a layout called action barlayout which has the tabs and images arranged, just reference the tabs at run time.
- Created a custom view called CCTab which represent the tabs of the action bar. When its touched it tells its listener (CCActionBar) its been touched.
- In my main layout xml file have an action bar container which I show or hide at runtime depending on the API level.
- Now in my main activity in my OnCreate method I check whether my API level is greater than 3.0 or not. If it is I just implement the standard ActionBar making sure my custom action bar container is invisible. If it isn't I set up my custom action bar and make sure my action bar container in my xml layout is visible.

  - Then I make sure that when a tab is pressed whilst using either method it is handled in the same way so once its setup you don't have to handle it any differently.

I hope this helps someone somewhere or at least give you an idea of how to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). It uses the native action bar for API >= 3 and provides backwards compatibility for API levels 2.x. There's also the Action Bar Compatibility sample project (listed as SupportAppNavigation, I believe). I think this is essentially the same thing.

Comment: I can't implement this without scrapping my map fragment support?

Comment: @DiscoS2 - To provide fragment support pre-3.0, you need to be using the compatibility library. ActionBarSherlock is an extension of the compatibility library, so I don't see why you would need to scrap map fragments support. Can you explain your concern a little more?

Comment: To implement google maps along with fragment capability I had to already use an extension of the compatibility library so my concern is that I can't use both extensions of the original library?

Comment: @DiscoS2 - ActionBarSherlock does not replace the compatibility library; it is built on top of it. I imagine that the google maps extension works the same way. If so, then unlikely (although possible, I suppose) that they will interfere with one another.

Comment: Ok thanks Ted. I guess I will give it a go. Bit of a hack though right? I just want the compatibility library to be fully complete and make supporting the different API levels seamless!

Comment: Just had a look into it and the problem is, I can't extend the Activity using both `SherlockFragmentActivity` and the `FragmentActivity` in the google support library?

Comment: @DiscoS2 - Looking at the sources for ActionBarSherlock, it seems `SherlockFragmentActivity` is derived (indirectly) from `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`. It should be plug-compatible.

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is to use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) to get the tabbed action bar functionality.

I assume that you also need a `MapView` support in `Fragment`. For this I would recommend solution from [MapView in a Fragment (Honeycomb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109336/mapview-in-a-fragment-honeycomb) 
(look at user1414726 answer with sample code).

I think it is a better solution than using library though it is using deprecated `LocalActivityManger`. But in my opinion it is a better idea than using library where every `Activity` is a subclass of `MapViewActivity` which I assume you are using.