# Android : Access Mapview Inside Fragment With ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mapview, android-viewpager

I am Using View Pager to Display three Views.

```
"Filter","Streets","Around"
```

Each View is Defined by Fragment.

**WHAT I WANT :**
I want to Use Mapview Inside My FilterFragment.

**WHAT I HAVE DONE :**

I want to Use MapView Inside Filter Fragment but Could Not Able to Run Successfully. and Getting  Log cate Error:

`android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView`

I have also Searched on Net and Stackoverflow about this Problem and Found the [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109336/mapview-in-a-fragment-honeycomb) and [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D%20viewpager%20fragment%20mapview) but Could not able to Found this link Related to my Problem as i am using Fragment  With ViewPager.

I have put my Code as Below.

Here is My Code for MainViewPager.java:

```
    package com.example.viewpageractivitydemo;

    import com.example.viewpageractivitydemo.viewpager.TitlePageIndicator;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class MainViewPager extends FragmentActivity {

        TestFragmentAdapter adapter;
        ViewPager pager;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(arg0);
            Log.i("MainViewPager","Inside Oncreate");
            setContentView(R.layout.mainviewpager);
            pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

            adapter = new TestTitleFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            pager.setAdapter(adapter);

            TitlePageIndicator indicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
            indicator.setViewPager(pager);
            pager.setCurrentItem(1);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onResume();

    //      pager.setCurrentItem(1);
        }

    }
```

Here is Code for TestFragmentAdapter.java

```
package com.example.viewpageractivitydemo;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.util.Log;

public class TestFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    protected static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "Filter",
            "Streets", "Around" };
    public String TAG = "TestFragmentAdapter";
    private int mCount = CONTENT.length;

    public TestFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG, "Inside getItemMethod with position " + position);

        if (position == 0) {
            Log.i("TestFragmentAdapter","Inside if Condition");
            return FilterFragment.newInstance(position);
        } else if (position == 1) {
            return StreetsFragment.newInstance(position);
        } else if (position == 2) {
            return AroundFragment.newInstance(position);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        // return MainFragment.newInstance(CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length]);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mCount;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        if (count > 0 && count <= 10) {
            mCount = count;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

Here is My Code for FilterFragment.java:

```
package com.example.viewpageractivitydemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FilterFragment extends Fragment {

    /*
     * @Override protected Class<? extends Activity> getActivityClass() { //
     * TODO Auto-generated method stub return MyFilterActivity.class; }
     */

    public static Fragment newInstance(int position) {

        Log.i("FilterFragment","Inside New Instasnce");
        FilterFragment filterFragment = new FilterFragment();
        return filterFragment;

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("FilterFragment","Inside OcCreateView");
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filter, null);
        return view;
    }

}
```

Here is My Code for filter.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#C6CDD4"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#93A4BA"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Where Am I"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/whereami_mapview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:apiKey="0-PaH6rk7RKrZSMd_lqdrZi6FazYyIlX5r6YFyA"
            android:clickable="true" />

        <!--
             <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/whereami_mapview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:apiKey="0-PaH6rk7RKrZSMd_lqdrZi6FazYyIlX5r6YFyA" />



        -->
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please Can anyone Suggest Me Answer to Solve My Problem. I have Spent many Hours on this. Still not getting any Idea about my Question. 
Thnks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `LocalActivityManager` to host a Activity inside a fragment. It is a deprecated class, but it offers the simplest solution.

Here is the code for a fragment (`MyFilterFragment` in your code). `YourMapActivity` is a basic activity that extends `MapActivity`.

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String KEY_STATE_BUNDLE = "localActivityManagerState";

    private LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager;

    protected LocalActivityManager getLocalActivityManager() {
        return mLocalActivityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle state = null;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            state = savedInstanceState.getBundle(KEY_STATE_BUNDLE);
        }

        mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(getActivity(), true);
        mLocalActivityManager.dispatchCreate(state);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            //This is where you specify you activity class
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), YourMapActivity.class); 
        Window w = mLocalActivityManager.startActivity("tag", i); 
        View currentView=w.getDecorView(); 
        currentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
        currentView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true); 
        ((ViewGroup) currentView).setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
        return currentView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBundle(KEY_STATE_BUNDLE,
                mLocalActivityManager.saveInstanceState());
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mLocalActivityManager.dispatchResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mLocalActivityManager.dispatchPause(getActivity().isFinishing());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mLocalActivityManager.dispatchStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mLocalActivityManager.dispatchDestroy(getActivity().isFinishing());
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:** Since this answer was posted, Google has released Google Maps Android API with fragment support with an official `MapFragment` class.

Comment: i have Used your Code but Dnt Knew While Running App i am facing ClassDefNotFound Problem. Dnt Knew Why. i have Declared it in Menifest file.

Comment: It Solves my Problem very Easily. Thnx for your Support. Thank you Very Much once again!!!!

Comment: It crashes when i swipe the the viewpager.
Error:the specified child already has a parent. you must call removeview() on the child's parent first.

Answer (score 0):

To use Google Maps, you have to extend `MapActivity`, which you didn't do. Check out [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview) in the docs. In the spirit of maintainability, I wouldn't resort to solutions that use deprecated functionality.

A more solid solution is to extend `MapActivity` and copy the missing implementation from `FragmentActivity`. If you don't want or need backwards compatiblity with older Android versions, just use `MapActivity` rather than `FragmentActivity`, which should already include the functionality needed to show `Fragment`s in Android 3.0 and later.

---

Edit: [here's a project that did it for you](https://github.com/petedoyle/android-support-v4-googlemaps).