# google map with the viewpager

Tags: android, google-maps, android-viewpager

In my application I am using the view-pager.I want to add the google map into one of the views of the view-pager. I search on the google but I don't get the proper solution.Finally I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/12873281/1263679 and apply but when I swipe then eclipse give error `The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first`. So please let me know How can I solve the error. and if there is any another solutions for the `google map with the viewpager`.

Thanks.

Please check my posted question [How to solve for viewpager : The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559353/how-to-solve-for-viewpager-the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent-you-must)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it by just add single line `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3)`;

Go.