# change Activity to Fragment with minimal changes

Tags: java, android, zxing

I have this activity:

```
public final class CaptureActivity extends Activity implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {
}
```

This activity capture QR code (from zxing lib). And I need change it to Fragment. I need to see Tabs and Status bar when scan QR code. I want something like this:

```
public final class CaptureActivity extends SherlockFragment implements
            SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    }
```

How do it with minimal changes?

Comment: Fragments are different classes with its own peculiarities. There's no such thing as "with minimal changes". You have to migrate your code and test/debug.

Comment: Maybe define an interface with `.asActivity()` and `.asFragment()` and use composition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be easily done using `LocalActivityManger`. It allows you to embed an activity inside a fragment. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873213/android-access-mapview-inside-fragment-with-viewpager/12873281#12873281) you can find sample code how to do it.

Comment: @IhorKostenko Did you eventually manage this? I'm attempting something similar if you can help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24754119/how-to-place-zxing-within-a-fragment