# android google map api v2 display error

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I have written a very simple android app to display google map using `google map api v2`. But when I run the app, it always ends itself at once.

Anybody could help me to figure out the mistake? 
And I have import the `google-play-services.jar`, `android-support-v4.jar` and have add "Add support Library"

The main three file as follow:

**1. MainActivity**

```
package edu.lore;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }
}
```

**2.activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

**3.AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="edu.lore"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />    
<permission
    android:name="edu.lore.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="edu.lore.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDFH436KisLnq4qY-55fVVOTePBIvMZOAo" />
</application>
```

Comment: Check the link below.
This might help you.                   
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8126287/951045

Comment: what kind of error you are getting?

Comment: Please post your logcat.

Comment: @user1999412 Have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please post the LogCat output?

I think a fragment is not allowed as root element of your layout file. The root element must be a ViewGroup, a View or a merge element. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html

Answer (score 0):

As the `MapFragment` is supported only for the api level 12 or above you need to use the `SupportMapFragment` instead as below:

> ```
> <fragment
>          android:id="@+id/map"
>          android:layout_width="match_parent"
>          android:layout_height="match_parent"
>          class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
> ```

and also check that you have enabled the service of `Google Maps Android API v2` in google console where you have registered your application.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It is required to use `SupportMapFragment` if `MinSdkVersion` is below 12

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```