# Google Maps Android API v2 and Eclipse

Tags: android, google-maps

I am new in Google Map and so many things aren't clear enough to me for that reason.So i expect some expert's direction on this regard.I read [This Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#adding_the_api_key_to_your_application) and did everything what it says.I use google map api v2 and get a map key.Then i make a sample project following that link and select target version android 2.2(while running the project).But a list of error occurs after running then example in eclipse android emulator.My **logcat** view shows:

```
01-31 00:51:59.226: W/dalvikvm(329): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.googleMapApp/com.googleMapApp.LocationProfileManagerActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at com.googleMapApp.LocationProfileManagerActivity.onCreate(LocationProfileManagerActivity.java:14)
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  ... 11 more
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.googleMapApp-1.apk]
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:544)
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
01-31 00:51:59.236: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
```

**My Manifest.xml** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.googleMapApp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <permission
    android:name="com.googleMapApp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.googleMapApp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<!-- Require OpenGL ES version 2 -->
     <uses-feature
      android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
      android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LocationProfileManagerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="myMapKey"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My **main.xml** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

My **activity.java** is:

```
package com.googleMapApp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class LocationProfileManagerActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    //private GoogleMap map;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

     }
}
```

Sorry for this lengthy description,but i want to show you exactly what i did.I think as a newcomer i did a lot of mistake on this way.so i expect someone will guide me that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android google map api v2 display error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453884/android-google-map-api-v2-display-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using features only available in later APIs, namely `Fragment`.  If you want to compile to support 2.2, you need to include the [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) in your project.  You will also have to make the following changes to use support fragments instead of regular fragments --

In main.xml, change

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

to

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

and in your activity.java, change

```
public class LocationProfileManagerActivity extends Activity {
```

to

```
public class LocationProfileManagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```

Comment: and see @Goldfish comment, you need to test on a real device.

Comment: 2.2 isn't mandatory for me(i use that because i don't know actually which android version supports google api v2).So which android version i should use so that i need not include that support library?is it android 4.2

Comment: @ridoy no its not mandatory, its a new version of google api compared to previous version, it is much better..

Comment: Yes i know it,but i want to know what minimum android version needed to use that api..@Mitesh?

Answer (score 1):

Maps API v2 cannot be run in an emulator because of its dependency on Google Play Services, which is bundled in  the Google Play Store .apk. It can be hacked together though, you can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445093/how-to-show-google-map-v2-on-android-emulator) on the first Google result for "Google maps v2 emulator". Also you can still use V1 for a limited time, you can get started [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/).

Answer (score 1):

you need to make two changes

Since as you are sdk version is below 12, need to make following change

1) 
**main.xml**

Replace

```
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

with

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

2) **activity.java**

Need to extend `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity`

If you want to test in emulator , then download the [**google_play_services_apk**](http://www.sendspace.com/filegroup/HDHwmDlVndx96Fa1jEzx8Q) and install it in emulator.