# display map in fragment of viewpager

Tags: android

I want to display Map in one of my `Fragment` I am using 4 fragments in which one shows the map  but i don't want to use `LocalActivityManager`to host a Activity inside a fragment. It is a deprecated class, but it offers the simplest solution.

By using `MapActivity` it is starting a new `Activity` which i don't want i want to display it in `viewpager` and `MapView` dont work in `Fragment`.
Please suggest me how to get it.

Thanks for Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no other way then the one mentioned in the following way...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8126287

Answer (score 1):

Since [Maps V1 (`MapActivity` and kin) is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey), you could consider moving to the [new Maps V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/), which has `MapFragment` (for native API Level 11 fragments) and `SupportMapFragment` (for the Android Support Library's backport of fragments).

Comment: can you give me some reference

Comment: @P_Pran: My answer contains hyperlinks. Using your mouse (or trackpad or other pointing device) you can click on the hyperlinks to view Web pages that contain documentation that you can read.